# How to calculate volatility in percentage

Tags: pine-script

Is there any formula for calculating volatility in percentage or just volatility?

'''
How to calculate volatility
In percent
'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the mean of the data set.

Calculate the difference between each data value and the mean.

Square the deviations.

Add the squared deviations together.

Divide the sum of the squared deviations by the number of data values.

Comment: please if possible can you tell the Pinescript code. By the way thanks

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript 5, `ta.atr` "Average True Range" is a measure of volatility.  You can convert to % pretty easily after that.